# Laravel 4 One To Many relationship Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am laravel newbie and I am trying to follow the documentation.So I have two models,  'User' model and a 'UserPhone' model. A user has many phones.

**User model:**

```php
public function userPhone() {    
    return $this->hasMany('UserPhone');
}
```

**UserPhone model:**

```php
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

On my controller I am trying to "copy" the documentation:

```php
$userPhone = User::find(1)->userPhone;
```

Well the result is an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I know that I am missing something here , but I cannot find it.

Comment: Are you respecting the Laravel convention in your DB? Such as having a primary key named 'id' for each table and having your foreign key named 'foreigntable_id'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you don't have an user with id of 1.

```php
$userPhone = User::find(1)->userPhone;
```

This should work, but, if it doesn't find the user the first part:

```php
User::find(1)
```

I will return a NULL and NULL is not an object, then you get the error: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

My advice is, try to do this

```php
var_dump( User::find(1) );
```

And you if you receive just a NULL, you found the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer , however if you look below, I have answered my own question, it was such a newbie mistake.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch Users with their related phone numbers (userPhone) you can use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

```php
//get all users (User) with their respective phonenumbers (userPhone)
$users = User::with('userPhone')->get() 

//get User with id==1, with his related phonenumbers (userPhone of User(1))
$user_1 = User::with('userPhone')->where('id',1)->first()
```

and than you can do

```php
if(!is_null($user))
$phones_of_user_1 = $user_1->userPhone();
else
$phones_of_user_1 = array();
```

That way, if a user of id==1 exists, you fetch his phone numbers. Else, you get an empty array and no exception/error (trying to get property on a non-object) thrown .

Answer (score 0):

That relationship would automatically be loaded for you.

```php
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->userPhone->id;
```

This is assuming you have your database tables are setup correctly according to laravel's conventions and you actually have a User with an ID of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is that everything was ok!
I had accidentaly left

```
 use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
```

before the UserPhone Model Class declaration..It was such a newbie mistake.

Answer (score -3):

1) You are missing a pair of () after userPhone

```
$userPhone = User::find(1)->userPhone();
```

2) You are not using the 'find' method properly. I think what you want to do is :

```
$userPhone = User::userPhone()->get();
```

or

```
$userPhone = User::find($phoneId);  //where $phoneId is the id of the phone you are trying to find.
```

The 'find' method return only one object and will try to find it with it's id.

Comment: Can you please tell me why i get 'unusefull answer' for this instead of just downrating me?